# what does the template in vue.js bind to?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, binding

I recently experienced a bug in my vue.js application. I was able to fix it, and it taught me something about how vue.js works. I want to know if I'm corret.

First of all, the bug:

```
    props: {
        property: {},
        ...
    }
```

```
    data(): {
        return {
            propertyData: {
                field1: null,
                field2: '',
                field3: [{email: null, notifying: false}]
            },
            ...
        };
    }
```

```
    created() {
        this.propertyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.property));
    }
```

I was trying to make a copy of the property prop and assigned that to propertyData as a means of being able to mutate propertyData without mutating the property prop directly. But this was causing issues in the template. It almost seemed like there was a disconnect between the propertyData object and whatever the template was binding to.

For example, I would add this to the template:

```
{{propertyData.field3}}
```

...and it would print to the screen:

```
[{email: null, notifying: false}]
```

...which is expected at first. But I have an email text field that binds to the email field in each object of field3:

```
<v-layout v-for="(item, index) in propertyData.field3" :key="index">
    <v-flex>
        <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            v-model="item.email"
            placeholder="username@example.com"
            :rules="[v => !!v || 'Email is required',
                v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Email is invalid' ]"
            maxlength="255"
            required>
        </v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

When I type something into the email field, the propertyData array doesn't update on the screen... that is, until the email field is validated (for example, when I finally add @ and the first character of the domain).

I would put console logs in the code and it would print out the correct output for propertyData. That is, it would print out exactly what I currently had in the email field even though, on the screen, it didn't.

Then I tried this instead:

```
created() {
    Object.assign(this.propertyData, {...this.property});
}
```

This fixed the problem. Now the propertyData.field3 array prints the actual current data entered into the email field and updates immediately.

So the lesson I learned from this (and this is what I'd like someone to confirm) is that the object the template binds to is not the data object (not directly at least). Once the component is created (or maybe mounted), any references to propertyData in the template, or to any of its fields, refers to the initial object defined in data() (with null for field1, '' for field2, etc.). But if you assign a completely different object to propertyData after that (which is what this.propertyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.property)) would do), the template doesn't change the object it binds to. It's still bound to the initial object (with null for field1, '' for field2, etc.) and it requires a rendering update (which validation would do) to update the object the template binds to to the object propertyData refers to. My fix worked because Object.assign(...) doesn't change the object propertyData refers to, it just changes (or adds to) the fields.

^ Is this correct?